# How to set up tight-binding calculations for Si-C system in LAMMPS?

Tags: lammps, tight-binding

In a project, I have to simulate the reaction between carbon nanotube (C) and molten silicon (Si) using LAMMPS. As far as I learned, there is not a classical force field capable to simulate the Si-C reaction, except for density-functional tight-binding calculations with LATTE library.

However, to use LATTE library, I still need two input files/folders: `latte.in` and `TBparams`. Where can I find a set of suitable parameters describing Si-C interation in order to configure the two input files/folders? Are there tutorial or documentation that explain the parameters and the standard way to prepare the two input files/folders?

Comment: "there is not a classical force field capable to simulate the Si-C reaction" - while I am not an expert in reaction dynamics etc, what about Tersoff potential? Tersoff potential has always worked well for me in the case of certain thermodynamic properties.

Comment: I have tried Tersoff potentials, although it is accurate in reproducing thermaldynamic properties, it cannot describe reaction.

Comment: I think there are no parameters available for Si-C interaction, one has to repeat the calculation done by Negre et al. for Silicon and Carbon to get the parameters.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky was the last comment by Magic_Number helpful? Did you figure anything out over the last 7 months? Are you still actively in need of an answer? Please update us!